# construct a object from array and achieve tab completion

Tags: typescript, object, types

need to use values from an array as keys to create a new object.

And need to achieve tap completion.

```
const keys = ['name', 'age', 'contact', 'response'];
let obj = {};
keys.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = row[key];
});
obj. //need to know what are the properties previously added.
```

Typescripts need to understand the object's name, age, and contact properties.

Comment: Are the keys static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// `as const` makes strings be string literals
const keys = ['name', 'age', 'contact', 'response'] as const;
// theese are the keys union ('name' | 'age' | ...)
type KeyType = typeof keys[number]
// row has data on what object will be
type RowType = typeof row
// the `obj` is the copy of `row` with only `keys` keys
type FullObjType = Pick<RowType, KeyType>
// the `obj` properties are not set yet
type ObjType = Partial<FullObjType>

let obj: ObjType = {};
for (let k of keys) {
  obj[key] = row[key]
}
let fullObj: FullObjType = obj;
```

Or the other way,

```
function PickKeys<T, K extends keyof T>(row: T, keys: K[]) {
   return Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, row[k]])) as Pick<T, K>
}
```

Comment: Can we able to have a equivalent for ```const keys = ['name', 'age', 'contact', 'response'] as const;``` in javascript

Comment: @Arunachalam The best I can suggest is to define `declare function myKeys<T>(o:T):(keyof T)[];` in d.ts, write it as `function myKeys(o){return Object.keys(o)}` in js and use it on `let a = myKeys({name: true, age: true, ...})`